# How to trigger a click outside event?

Tags: javascript, click, mouseevent, cypress

I'm writing unit testing and e2e testing for a popover component in React.
I should check if the popup is hidden when I click outside the component.
I'm using Jest + Enzyme for unit testing and Cypress for e2e testing.
Does anybody know how to do this?

I've tried as follows in cypress.

```
cy.get('[data-test-id="popover-container"]').click(-20, -20, {force: true});
```

But the clicked point is actually outside of the popup window, but it doesn't work.
`react-tiny-popover` library is used to show the popover as follows:

```
<Popover
      content={({ position, targetRect, popoverRect }) => (
        <ArrowContainer
          position={position}
          targetRect={targetRect}
          popoverRect={popoverRect}
          arrowColor={'#ccc'}
          arrowSize={10}
        >
          <div data-test-id="popover-container">
            <Content/>
          </div>
        </ArrowContainer>
      )}
      isOpen={visible}
      onClickOutside={() => hideOnOutsideClick && setVisible(false)}
      position={position}
    >
      <div onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>{children}</div>
    </Popover>
```

Comment: why don't you select an element that you know is outside of the popover-container and click it?

Comment: I tried it already and it's working. But not sure what is the best practise.

Comment: And also, how to do it in unit testing with Jest and Enzyme?

Answer (score 34):

You can simply click somewhere on the body:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('clickOutside', function(): Chainable<any> {
  return cy.get('body').click(0,0); //0,0 here are the x and y coordinates
});
```

In test:

```
cy.get('[data-test-id="popover-container"]').clickOutside();
```

[click reference](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click.html#Usage)

Answer (score 13):

Taken from the other answer you can just:

```js
cy.get('body').click(0,0);
```

No need to add a command unless you are going to use it many times